# Comparing different versions of a Java project

Tags: eclipse, versioning

I am not an experienced Java developer and I am currently modifying and re-building a plugin project. I am about to adopt a versioning control system (e.g. Subclipse), however I already have several versions of such project. My intention is that to check how these versions differs from each other and I was wondering what is the best approach into this. I work with Eclipse IDE.

Thank indeed,

I.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclipse just connects Eclipse with a Subversion repository.  You have to have a Subversion repository somewhere for Subclipse to work.

Assuming you have a Subversion repository, you commit the oldest version first.  You create a Eclipse workspace on you computer that you'll use to communicate with Subversion.  First, you copy the oldest version of your project into the Eclipse workspace.  Then you commit the workspace.  You update your workspace by copying each saved version to your Eclipse workspace in turn, and commit.

That way, the source control will be able to show you the differences between each saved version.

Comment: Thanks Gilbert, this helps a lot. I.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl click on the root of the two projects, Right click, then Compare With -> Each Other

Pro tip: use a better source control system than svn, like Bazaar, Git, or Mercurial

Comment: Want to explain *why* Bazaar, Git or Mercurial are better than svn?

Comment: @meriton not particularly; it's an aside (not central to my answer), and easy to google.

Comment: @artbristol Thanks indeed, I was not aware of Bazaar. I had few issues with MercurialEclipse, but I will go back to it and try again.